How to solve second-order objective function with orthogonal constraint
I want to minimize $tr(P^TAP-P^TB)$ with the constraint $P^TP=I$.
$P, A, B$ are all matrices, $I$ is the identity matrix, $tr$ means the trace of a matrix.
P: size(m,l)
A: size(m,m) non-symmetric matrix
B: size(m,l)
I try to write the Lagrangian function as $L=tr(P^TAP-P^TB)+\delta^T(P^TP-I)$, calculate the derivative  of $L$ with respect to $P$, and make the derivative to zero:
$(A+A^T)P+P(\delta+\delta^T)=B$, while yieds $( (I\otimes (A+A^T))+((\delta+\delta^T)\otimes I))vec(P)=vec(B)$, where $vec$ is the vectorization operator. I then use the conjugate gradient method to update $P$.
The $\delta$ is updated as $\delta=\delta+c(P^TP-I)$
However, $P$ obtained by the above procedure cannot meet the orthogonal constraint. I write the code using Matlab. I don't know whether the optimization process is right. Can anyone help me, is there a better optimized solution to the problem? Many thanks!

a variant of the weighted procrustus problem?
